# What is the definitive Initial D collection box?

Tags: merchandise, initial-d

I've already watched every episode from the series (downloaded from torrent sites), but wanted to buy an official box since I feel bad about not having the original stuff.

I wanted to know if there is a definitive dvd/bluray box edition. I always struggled with finding decent quality video/audio.

Ideally there would be a Blu-ray collection in 720p at least and with 5.1 DTS Japanese audio.

By making a quick search on ebay, I found [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Initial-D-COMPLETE-BD-BOX-Vol-1-Blu-ray-4988064741533-AVXA-74153-Anime-/400660945522?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5d4940da72), which is scheduled to release in a few days, but I don't know exactly it's specifications.

Where should I be looking for this stuff? It would obviously be ideal if English subtitles were available, but I guess I'm stuck with Japanese releases if quality is concerned.

Comment: should give [archonia](http://www.archonia.com) a shot

Comment: I know you can find the DVD's at http://www.funimation.com/shows/initial-d/products 480p 5.1 but no info on BD yet as they seem to be coming out in 2 days in Japan.

Comment: I've heard the English releases are censored and stuff, at least in the First Stage. I would like the best version, even if I have to setup subtitles myself later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Japan pre-orders for the new two-box "complete" premium BD box set for 31,080 yen each (Amazon price as of this post).

[The first BD box set, Vol .1](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00G93OE5Y)  is scheduled to be released February 21th, 2014 and includes 6 BDs + 3 CDs, featuring:

```
#Initial D: First Stage (26 eps)
#Initial D: Second Stage (13 eps)
---
#CD: Radio Stage Part 1
#CD: EXTRA-DRAMA CD Vol. 1 & 2
```

Notes from [CD Japan](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/detailview.html?KEY=AVXA-74153):

> First Premium Blu-ray Box release including complete first stage (26 episodes), second stage (13 episodes), special CD Vol1 "Initial D Radio Stage Part1", special CD 2 "EXTRA-DRAMA CD Vol.1&2"(2 discs), special original goods (2 kinds), and special manual book in a deluxe box.

---

[The second BD box set, Vol. 2](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00G93OE2W) is scheduled to be released March 21th and includes 7 BDs + 3 CDs

```
#Initial D: Third Stage (Movie)
#Initial D: Fourth Stage (24 eps)
#Initial D: Extra Stage (4 eps)
#Initial D: Battle Stage (2 eps)
#Initial D to the Next Stage - Project D e Mukete (1 eps)
---
#CD: Radio Stage Part 2
#CD: EXTRA-DRAMA CD Vol.3 & 4
```

Notes from [CD Japan](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/detailview.html?KEY=AVXA-74159):

> Second Premium Blu-ray Box release including third stage (movie), fourth stage (24 episodes), extra stage (3 episodes), battle stage (2 episodes), project episode, special CD Vol1 "Initial D Radio Stage Part2", special CD 2 "EXTRA-DRAMA CD Vol.3&4"(2 discs), special original goods (2 kinds), and special manual book in a deluxe box.

**NOTE:** The discs are **region-free** and contain **NO** subtitles.

Currently only the *Fifth Stage* (14 eps), the upcoming movie (slated for summer 2014) and "Final Stage" (not yet produced) are missing from the collection.

Comment: Well I know about this set as I stated in the question, but I still don't know anything about video/audio format. Do you have any info on that?

Comment: The episodes are remastered in Blu-ray quality. The Blu-ray itself is a Blu-ray hybrid so it plays on DVD players, too. It's standard 16:9 (1.78:1) aspect ratio. The [official FB page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/%E9%A0%AD%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97-DInitial-DOfficial-Site/662201660486276) has some more photos of the box and discs.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. I never knew this hybrid Blu-ray thing existed. Also, has it been confirmed to be 720p or 1080p video quality?

Comment: I couldn't find any information about the resolution. I don't think they redid the cel-animations, and since some seasons like Second Stage was digitally animated at a (ridiculously) low resolution (or lack of smoothing). So the big question probably is the first set a new HD telecine or an upscale from a composite source? But judging my the ~30s clip on the official FB page for the release there seems to be some significant improvements.

Comment: Could you provide the link for this 30s video? I did not find any videos on the page besides the new movie trailer.

Comment: Ignore that I said about the trailer, I didn't read the description. Here's a link to one of the commercials: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RH0P7wrLSEo

Comment: Oh I see that oO. Well, will have to seriously consider getting this now.